# how to make a regexp in js split to break using special text characters

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I need help to make this work in JS:
a="casa-me,pois estou farto! Eis a lista:uma;duas;três." 
a.split(/regex/) to return

```
a=["casa","me","pois","estou","farto","Eis","a","lista","uma","duas","três"]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check my answer to see if it's what you want. It seems to be the only one actually working to get you that result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers seem to miss things like accented characters, etc. This seems to be working well against your test string, though:

```js
var re = /[^A-zÀ-ÿ]+/g; 
var str = 'casa-me,pois estou farto! Eis a lista:uma;duas;três';
 
var result = str.split(re);

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
a.match(/\w+/g).join(' ');
```

Comment: sorry, after saving, the break lines dissappeard, i correct the post.

Comment: then use it without .join() and you get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a global matching regex (note the g modifier):

`yourString.replace(/[,;:.!]/g, ' ')`

Comment: Note that if you want any non-word character you may change `[,;:.!]` to be `\W` instead

Answer (score 0):

Regexp is something very nice.

```
var a = 'casa-me,pois estou farto! Eis a lista:uma;duas;três.';

var array = a.match(/[àáâãèéêẽìíîĩòóôõùúûũ\w]+/g);
```

Each `array` position will have a word as you want.